# How to make a redirection loop

Tags: bash, io-redirection

This one is mostly for academic reasons. ;-)

Consider the following Bash statement:

```
foo | bar
```

This executes two processes, `foo` and `bar`, such that the standard-out of `foo` is connected to the standard-in of `bar`. So far, so good.

Is there a way to invoke `foo` and `bar` so that we *also* have a connection in the opposite direction?

```
foo.stdout -> bar.stdin
foo.stdin  <- bar.stdout
```

As I understand it, Bash calls `pipe(2)` to create a pair of FDs connected to each other, which can then be used to replace `stdin` / `stdout` in the respective child processes. At the kernel level, I see no reason why you couldn't call `pipe(2)` twice and arrange the circular arrangement depicted above.

But I can't figure out the shell syntax to actually *do* that.

So far, the best idea I can come up with is to use named pipes, or maybe to launch a subshell and do some crazy FD-to-FD redirecting somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, you can do it with either a **coproc** (bash has lousy support for multiple coprocs, but you only need one here):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
coproc { while read -r line; do echo "$BASHPID read: $line";  done; }
i=0; while :; do
    echo "$BASHPID writing>> $i"
    echo $i >&"${COPROC[1]}"
    read -r line <&"${COPROC[0]}"
    echo "$BASHPID coproc produced>> $line"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

or **named pipes** (those work in simple POSIX shells too):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpd"' EXIT
tmpd=$(mktemp -d)

mkfifo "$tmpd/p0" "$tmpd/p1"
exec 3<>"$tmpd/p0"
exec 4<>"$tmpd/p1"
rm -rf "$tmpd"

( while read -r line; do echo "$BASHPID read: $line";  done; ) <&3 >&4  &
i=0; while :; do
    echo "$BASHPID writing>> $i" 
    echo $i >&3
    read -r line <&4
    echo "$BASHPID coproc produced>> $line"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

They both might seem ugly if you're not used to fd-handling in shells.

Also, due to the effect pipes have on scheduling (writing to pipes with a full pipe buffer blocks you as does reading from a pipe with an empty one), you might get deadlocked with certain read/write patterns.

Outputs of the above two examples might look like this:

```
32435 writing>> 0
32435 coproc produced>> 32441 read: 0
32435 writing>> 1
32435 coproc produced>> 32441 read: 1
32435 writing>> 2
32435 coproc produced>> 32441 read: 2
32435 writing>> 3
32435 coproc produced>> 32441 read: 3
32435 writing>> 4
32435 coproc produced>> 32441 read: 4
```

Comment: In fact, `bash` supports only *one* co-process at a time. The `bash` manual mentions this under the "BUGS" heading ;-)  `ksh` [supports more](http://board.issociate.de/thread/7504/Maximum-number-of-coprocesses-in-korn-shell.html) (unclear how many).

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that's what I meant by "lousy support". Experimental support for more can be compiled in, though.

Comment: Looks like named pipes is probably the way to do this. Interesting about `coproc` though...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it with a pipe (`|`), but it's easy to do with asynchronous processes writing and reading each other.

This `ksh93` script (*`bash` version further down*) starts up two `while`-loops which toss a number in-between them, adding one to the number in each transaction:

```
while read data; do
    print $(( data + 1 ))
done |&

print -p 1

while read -p data; do
    print $(( data + 1 ))
done >&p
```

1. The first loop is started as a co-process. It waits for input on its `read`.
2. The number `1` is given to the `read` of the co-process to start the whole thing off.
3. The second loop is started doing the same thing as the first loop, but not as a co-process.

Running it with `xtrace` enabled (and with a modified script that sets `PS4`, the trace prompt, to `"& "` for the first loop, and to `"> "` for the second loop, just to show what's what):

```
$ ksh -x script.sh
& PS4='& '
> PS4='> '
> print -p 1
> 1>& p
> read -p data
& read data
& print 2
& read data
> print 3
> read -p data
& print 4
> print 5
> read -p data
& read data
& print 6
& read data
> print 7
> read -p data
(etc.)
```

`bash` also does co-processes (look for the `coproc` builtin), but I have less familiarity with those. You can probably do this in a shell without co-processes too.

**EDIT**: Something like this for `bash`:

```
coproc while read data; do
    echo $(( data + 1 ))
done

echo 1 >&${COPROC[1]}

while read -u ${COPROC[0]} data; do
    echo $(( data + 1 ))
done >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Running it (with modified trace prompt as above):

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ PS4='& '
& PS4='> '
> echo 1
> read -u 63 data
& read data
& echo 2
> echo 3
> read -u 63 data
& read data
& echo 4
> echo 5
> read -u 63 data
& read data
& echo 6
> echo 7
> read -u 63 data
(etc.)
```

Answer (score 1):

For more complicated file-descriptor redirection trees, there's also [pipexec](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec), which has made it into the [Debian Repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pipexec).

Truly, it's a limitation of the syntax in BASH and in Bourne-like shells in general.

Comment: Right. So `pipexec` (where it exists) is a general utility for building arbitrary stream redirection graphs among processes. That's interesting to know.