# How to have two-way (read-write) interaction with a program from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

So typically when you redirect input with a command like `find . | grep -i pineapple` it just evaluates `find .`, and that comprises all of the input for `grep -i pineapple`.

However, I need to write a script that runs a program, gives it some input, reads some of the output, keeps the program running, and then sends some more input, based on the output earlier.
For instance consider a C program that uses `scanf` twice, if I redirect normally I have to specify the input for both calls to `scanf` before running the program, however what I want to give to the second call to scanf depends on what the program outputs between the two calls.

I've tried doing it with `./pineapple >&0 <&1 &` so I can just access the programs input and output as stdout and stdin, but that didn't work, not sure what I was expecting. The input is in binary format, and what the program outputs will not always be the same for the same input, if that's relevant. Is there any easy way I can do what I described?

Comment: So your `pinapple` is basically an interactive program? The way to script on top of interactive programs is usually by using `expect` (which I know nothing about).

Comment: I wouldn't call it an "interactive program" it only reads and writes data twice, it's a binary file from a CTF challenge. I've actually tried using expect, but I think it has problems with the non-text format.

Comment: @ThomasKlingler, can you link to that CTF?

Comment: Have a look at the `coproc` command and bash coprocesses.  This creates a bi-directional pipe that you can read/write to between your script and the other program.

Comment: I will have a look at that, thank you. The CTF is here: https://pwnable.tw/

Comment: I'd use netcat to read inputs from a socket, check this out: ```nc -vv -l -p 12345 -e /bin/bash``` it transforms bash in a server that receives commands over the network on port 12345.

Comment: Related: [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270)

Comment: Have you seen [How to make a redirection loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294733/how-to-make-a-redirection-loop)?  The accepted answer covers both `coproc` and named pipes.

Comment: My instinct is for a pair of named pipes, but they will block if much data remains unread (in the order of kilobytes), so you need to have some flow control in your transferred data.

Comment: I have used `expect` to automate interactions with programs and hardware devices. Mild learning curve.